# Quick and dirty Java wiki

Tags: java, tomcat, wiki, war

I'm looking for *any* wiki software that deploys as a WAR with (preferably) an embedded DB; thus "zero config". Something that runs inside a simple web container like Tomcat or Jetty.

So far the closest thing I've been able to find is XWiki, but even that is not zero config and comes with a whole slew of instructions for setting up correctly.

I'm looking for a WAR I can just hot-deploy and then use by going to its web console. Does such an artifact exist?!?!

Comment: I doubt it. An embedded, zero-config DB is fine if your data set is small. But a wiki should be expected to deal with at least a moderately large number of entries, so it would need a real DB, and that always requires some configuration.

Comment: Quick is over fast dirty remains a long long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has used [vqwiki](http://www.vqwiki.org/downloads.php) and was quite satisfied with it. I remember that the config overhead was very low. Not sure if it was zero, though.

Answer (score 3):

[JAMWiki](http://jamwiki.org/wiki/en/JAMWiki) uses an internal database (HSQL) by default and is basically just a WAR file you can deploy in a [few easy steps](http://jamwiki.org/wiki/en/Installation#New_Installs). Many versions ago (pre-1.0), I installed it on Tomcat 5.5 in a few minutes.  JAMWiki uses basically the same wiki-markup that Wikipedia / MediaWiki uses.

Answer (score 0):

[Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview) ships with an internal DB.

Not that you should use it. It can be running within minutes. IIRC there's a quick web-based init.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dave - I'll check it out.